# Back4app issue in registering device with ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, back4app

I m trying to use `back4app` for push notification. For this I have installed `back4app`'s ionic sdk (https://www.back4app.com/docs/ionic/parse-ionic-sdk) like this

`npm install parse`

then in my `app.component.ts` I imported parse

```
import Parse from 'parse';
```

and in platform ready

```
Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
Parse.initialize("APP_ID_HERE", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY"); //I have used real keys from back4app dashboard.

let  install = new Parse.Installation();

install.save(null, {
    success: (install) => {
      // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
       // console.clear();
        console.error('New object created with objectId: ' + install.id);
    },
    error: (install, error) => {
      // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      //console.clear();
      console.error('Failed to create new object, with error code:' + error.message.toString());
    }
});
```

When I do Ionic serve or test it in device, it should register device/installation id to their backend but it gives `400  Bad Request error on https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_Installation` the error was -

```
{"code":135,"error":"deviceType must be specified in this operation"}
```

I m not sure where to mention `deviceType` as their documentation doesn't seem that good.

Can anybody help me on this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not mentioned in their documentation but I have found it in one of their example.

Replacing -

```
let  install = new Parse.Installation();
```

with

```
 let  install = new Parse.Installation();
 install.set("deviceType", platform.platforms().toString());
```

Solved the issue.

[Here is the link to their repository](https://github.com/back4app/ionic-quickstart-example/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Parse SDK now supports `Promises`.

I'd recommend using it instead of passing in callbacks.

You can accomplish that by:

```js
install.save().then(() => {
  // success
}, err => {
  // error
})
```